# Orientdb - Spring boot application with embedded jetty not starting because it could not bind to properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, orientdb, embedded-jetty

I have a spring boot application I just built using Orientdb as my NoSQL database, the application was working fine until I added orientdb dependencies to enable me work with orientDb's Java api.I pasted the exceptions below.
 I tried removing the dependencies one by one and I discovered the error occurred each time I add this particular dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
            <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Here is the trace of the exceptions:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=server, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
```

Comment: Did you run also an embedded server of orientdb?

Comment: No I didn't. I had my orientdb server running separately from my application